# How to make a sound once a process is complete?

Tags: command-line, notification

I have started a long process through a terminal. Is it possible to make the Ubuntu terminal make a sound once the process is complete? This way, I don’t need to keep checking, but will instead be notified through a sound.

Comment: Can you explain further what do you mean with *process complete*?

Comment: @Lucio control is returned back to the terminal

Comment: Do you mean, open an application from terminal and when it finish, make a sound? Do you have an Ubuntu server or you mean GUI software?

Comment: yes exactly. For example i start a command line program, and once it exits and control is returned back to the terminal, a sound is made. I am currently using Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Same question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8607/how-can-i-play-a-sound-when-script-execution-is-ready

Comment: Play the ASCII bell sound: https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/how-to-make-a-sound-once-a-process-is-complete/1213564#1213564

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There are at least three command line ways to accomplish this by putting the suiting command at the end of your script you may invoke for your lengthy process:

1. The "classical" way to play a sound is to use [beep](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=beep).

   Beep will make a tone through the PC speaker. However this will not work in all cases (e.g. in my system PC speakers are completely disabled) You may have to remove `pcspkr` from `/etc/modprobe/blacklist.conf` and load the `pcspkr` kernel module:

   ```
   sudo sed -i 's/blacklist pcspkr/#blacklist pcspkr/g' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   sudo modprobe pcspkr
   beep [optional parameters]
   ```
2. We can also play any sound file in wav format using aplay (installed by default):

   ```
    aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Side_Right.wav
   ```
3. Another way is to use the pulseaudio command line interface to enable playback of any sound files your system (in `libsndfile`) recognizes on the default audio output:

   ```
     paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
   ```

We can use default sound files from `/usr/share/sounds/`, or any other sound file we may have in a different location.

---

Just to have mentioned it, there is another nice way to achieve this by misusing **espeak**, which is installed by default in Ubuntu <= 12.04. See, or rather hear the following example:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

c=10; while [ $c -ge 0 ]; do espeak $c; let c--; done; sleep 1 ## here lengthy code
espeak "We are done with counting"
```

In Ubuntu >= 12.10 Orca uses speak-dispatcher. We can then install [espeak](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=espeak), or alternatively use `spd-say "Text"`.

Comment: @Takkat I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and *espeak* is currently not installed.

Comment: @Lucio: yeah, now that you say it... They switched to speak-dispatcher. If this works (it does not on my system) see edit for using `spd-say`.

Comment: @Takkat The `spd-say` utility is installed by default and it works on my system.

Comment: Also take a look to this [Q/A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/611874/how-do-you-make-your-terminal-play-a-sound-or-offer-a-notification-when-it-has-f)

Comment: The pcspkr module is disabled by default so beep doesn't work unless you modprobe pcspkr and you also have to remove it from /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

Comment: And now I am listening to hamlet through espeak by `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amangalore/WordReader/master/hamlet.txt && cat hamlet.txt|espeak` .... lol!

Comment: I had good success with `paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga`

Comment: @Takkat, Thanks so much for the suggestions on how to play different sounds. I still don't understand how to get it to play after the process is finished though. Also, is there a way to make terminator do it by default or would I always have to start my processes with some additional instructions?
I'm using Linux Mint 19.1 if that is important.

Comment: @Kajsa you need to make a script that starts the process then gives out sound. Just like I did in the example in the last paragraph. Good luck!

Answer (score 152):

I use

```
make; spd-say done
```

Replace "make" with whatever long-running command you use.

Comment: `spd-say 'get back to work`'.  And comes pre-installed as well: http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.manifest , for blind people I suppose? And `-w` for infinite loops: `while true; do spd-say -w 'get back to work you lazy bum'; done`.

Comment: For me, it read out a really long error message. XD

Comment: doesn't seem to work in WSL2, unfortunately

Comment: It works with WSL2 with me

Comment: Tip: if you add commas to the string, it will make pauses.
`spd-say 'ERROR, I MADE A PAUSE'`

Answer (score 37):

According to [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html) the `\a` character escapes ASCII code 7, which is the computer's beep.

So `echo $'\a'` works to make a beep sound on my local machine, even when it's executed on a bash shell running on a computer I'm connected to via a terminal interface like PuTTY.

Comment: amazing! that's the easiest and best solution (at least for me) because it does not require to install any 3rd-party apps and can even be typed/pasted in the middle of the process to be run after command prompt will take focus.

Comment: the sound of this character is disabled in most modern terminals by default

Comment: What is the dollar sign for?

Comment: @Max `$` followed by an expression in single quotes is treated in a special way by Bash.  It is nonstandard and will not work in the standard UNIX Bourne shell.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925879/what-does-n-mean-in-bash

Comment: this works for me on both macOS Terminal.app and iTerm2 locally and logged into a remote server on ssh. However, it does *not* work when I am in a `screen` session.

Comment: a followup to my last comment; turns out that in `screen` you might need to adjust your "audio bell" setting, either via `.screenrc` or from inside the screen typing Ctrl+A, Ctrl+G to toggle the setting on/off. On one of my newer servers, the version of `screen` installed flashes a message at the bottom telling you the setting was changed, but in my older servers with older `screen`, no message is shown but the setting is changed and audio beeps work after toggling the setting

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83958/144861 , https://superuser.com/questions/806511/how-can-i-ring-the-audio-bell-within-a-bash-script-running-under-gnu-screen

Comment: Works for me local and remote via SSH with tmux when using `echo \a` without $ and quotes. But, I am using fish on both.

Answer (score 31):

### TL;DR

To play a sound after command finishes:

```bsh
long-running-command; sn3
```

(where `sn3` is sound number 3) put this in `.bashrc`:

```bsh
sound() {
  # plays sounds in sequence and waits for them to finish
  for s in $@; do
    paplay $s
  done
}
sn1() {
  sound /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/dialog-information.ogg
}
sn2() {
  sound /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
}
sn3() {
  sound /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/suspend-error.oga
}
```

Or read below for more options:

### Different sound on error and success

Here is what I use for exactly what you ask for - with one difference: it not only plays a sound when the command finishes but it plays a **different** sound on success and on error. (But you can change it if you don't like it.)

I have a Bash function called `oks` that I use at the end of long running commands:

```bsh
make && make test && make install; oks
```

It plays a sound and displays OK or ERROR (with error code) when the previous command finishes.

### Source code

Here is that function with two helpers:

```bsh
sound() {
  # plays sounds in sequence and waits for them to finish
  for s in $@; do
    paplay $s
  done
}
soundbg() {
  # plays all sounds at the same time in the background
  for s in $@; do
    # you may need to change 0 to 1 or something else:
    pacmd play-file $s 0 >/dev/null
  done
}
oks() {
  # like ok but with sounds
  s=$?
  sound_ok=/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/dialog-information.ogg
  sound_error=/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/dialog-warning.ogg
  if [[ $s = 0 ]]; then
    echo OK
    soundbg $sound_ok
  else
    echo ERROR: $s
    soundbg $sound_error
  fi
}
```

### Installation

You can put it in your ~/.bashrc directly or put it in some other file and then put this line in your ~/.bashrc:

```bsh
. ~/path/to/file/with/function
```

### Configuration

Change `sound_ok` and `sound_error` to some other sounds.

You can experiment with `sound` vs. `soundbg` and change `sound_ok` and `sound_error` to use sequences of many sounds that you like to get the result that you want.

### Good sounds

To find some good sounds on your system you can try:

```bsh
for i in /usr/share/sounds/*/stereo/*; do echo $i; paplay $i; sleep 1; done
```

Here are some sounds that I often use that are available on Ubuntu by default that are good for notifications - sn1 is loud and nice, sn2 is very loud and still pretty nice, sn3 is extremely loud and not so nice:

```bsh
sn1() {
  sound /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/dialog-information.ogg
}
sn2() {
  sound /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga
}
sn3() {
  sound /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/suspend-error.oga
}
```

Again, you can change `sound` to `soundbg` if you want to play it in the background without waiting for the sound to finish (e.g. to not slow down your scripts when you play a lot of sounds).

### Silent version

And just in case - here is the same function as `oks` but without sounds:

```bsh
ok() {
  # prints OK or ERROR and exit status of previous command
  s=$?
  if [[ $s = 0 ]]; then
    echo OK
  else
    echo ERROR: $s
  fi
}
```

### Usage

Here is how you use it:

Example with success:

```bsh
ls / && ls /bin && ls /usr; oks
```

example with error:

```bsh
ls / && ls /bim && ls /usr; oks
```

Of course in practice the commands are more like:

```bsh
make && make test && make install; oks
```

but I used `ls` so you could quickly see how it works.

You can use `ok` instead of `oks` for a silent version.

Or you can use e.g.:

```bsh
ls / && ls /bim && ls /usr; ok; sn1
```

to print OK/ERROR but always play the same sound, etc.

### Update

I put those functions on GitHub, see:

- https://github.com/rsp/scripts/blob/master/ok-functions.md

The source can be downloaded from:

- https://rawgit.com/rsp/scripts/master/ok-functions

### Update 2

I added a `soundloop` function to the above repo. It plays a sound and can be interrupted by Ctrl+C (unlike a simple `while true; do paplay file.ogg; done` that one would expect to work but it doesn't) as asked by **shadi** in the comments. It is implemented as:

```bsh
soundloop() {
  set +m
  a=`date +%s`
  { paplay $1 & } 2>/dev/null
  wait
  b=`date +%s`
  d=$(($b-$a))
  [ $d -eq 0 ] && d=1
  while :; do
    pacmd play-file $1 0 >/dev/null
    sleep $d
  done
}
```

If you think it is complicated, please direct your complains to PulseAudio developers.

Comment: I tried to put this in a `while true; do paplay ...; done` so that the sound repeats until I hit `Ctrl+C`, but when I do, it doesn't break. I can't find any special options in `man paplay` to figure out how to get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @shadi See my updated answer for a solution with a sound that repeats until you hit Ctrl+C.

Comment: @shadi `while true; do { paplay "$1" & wait; } 2>/dev/null; done`

Comment: The synthetized version of `complete.oga` could be `play -q -n -t alsa synth 1 pl E7`

Answer (score 9):

The command

```
 speaker-test
```

makes a noise sound. Simplest but annoying solution. :-)

Look at the [manual of `speaker-test(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/speaker-test.1.html) for options to configure the noise signal.

**Update**

If you do not mind installing sox, you can play Silicon Heaven Hymn:

```
sudo apt install sox
while true; do play -q -v 100 -n synth  .$(( $RANDOM % 51 ))1  sine $((200 + $RANDOM % 4000 )) &> /dev/null; done
```

If you do not mind to install espeak:

```
sudo apt install espeak
espeak 'Johnny is marching home! Hurray!'
espeak -v german  'Doch! Ich bin vertig!'
espeak -x  -v czech  'Běžela Magda kaňonem, srážela banány ramenem.'
```

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on Michael Curries's answer, you could make Bash print a `BEL` (`\a`) character through `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='printf \\a'
```

Setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` that way will make Bash execute `printf \\a` at the end of each command, which will make the terminal play a sound (though as muru points out, simply triggering the redrawal of the prompt will make the terminal play the sound, i.e. the sound will be played each time a new prompt is drawn, for example even when just hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd>).

This is a terminal feature, so it might not work across all terminals; for example it doesn't work in the console (but I'm sure it works in `gnome-terminal`and  `xterm`).

Comment: (with the caveat that every time you press Enter, you'll get a sound)

Answer (score 6):

This is not what you asked but you could use notification for that.

Replace the command given in the other answers with

```
notify-send "Process terminated" "Come back to the terminal, the task is over"
```

Comment: I went to add a shorthand to my .bashrc to do this, and I realised ubuntu already had one! ex: `sleep 10; alert`

Answer (score 4):

### Super simple answer

Play the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) [Bell Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) sound:

```bash
echo -e "\a"
```

Do it after a long command, emulated by `sleep 2` here:

```bash
sleep 2; echo -e "\a"
```

DONE!

### More details

To make this easy to use, add this to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file (create this file if it doesn't exist). Or, if using Ubuntu, add it to your `~/.bash_aliases` file instead (which file is imported by Ubuntu's default `~/.bashrc` file) [like I do in my `~/.bash_aliases` file here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.bash_aliases#L159):

```bash
# Play sound; very useful to add to the end of a long cmd you want to be notified of when it completes!
# Ex: `long_cmd; gs_sound_bell` will play a bell sound when `long_cmd` completes!
alias gs_sound_bell="echo -e \"\a\""

# Even better, have a pop-up notification too!
# Ex: `long_cmd; gs_alert` will play the sound above *and* pop up a notification when complete!
# See more details & a screenshot of the popup on my answer here:
#   https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/how-to-make-a-sound-once-a-process-is-complete/1213564#1213564
# For other popup window options, see my other answer here:
#   https://superuser.com/questions/31917/is-there-a-way-to-show-notification-from-bash-script-in-ubuntu/1310142#1310142
alias gs_alert="gs_sound_bell; alert \"task complete\""
```

Notice that my `gs_alert` alias calls `alert`, so you need that alias defined too. This alias is defined by default in Ubuntu. But, if your `~/.bashrc` file doesn't already have this near the top of it, then add it just above the code above. Again, these lines come default in your `~/.bashrc` file in Ubuntu 18 or 20, for instance:

```bash
# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

#### Test it

Close and re-open your terminal, or call `. ~/.bashrc` to re-"source" the file, then test it like this:

```bash
sleep 2; gs_alert
```

After 2 seconds you'll hear the bell sound and see this pop up at the top of your screen: [image]

If you ever forget what your alias contains, you can see what's in each one by running this:

```bash
# See the definitions for ALL aliases you have defined!
alias 

# See just the definitions for specific aliases. Ex:
alias gs_sound_bell
alias gs_alert 
alias alert
```

#### Use it

```bash
# get alerted when `my_long_cmd` finishes! Ex: building software. 
my_long_cmd; gs_alert
```

### Notes

1. The `gs_` part at the beginning of each alias is my initials. I prepend my custom commands and aliases with this to make them easy to find: I can now just type `gs_` at the terminal then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> (<kbd>Tab</kbd> twice) to see all my custom commands print out.

### See also

1. See also my "Bash one-line alarm script" here: [Ask Ubuntu: Alarm clock for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1500350/327339)

### Going Further

1. If you find this useful, you'll find a lot more of my Linux settings, including everything above, here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles.

   1. Check out [my `home` directory](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/home).
2. For other window popup options, see my other answer here: [SuperUser.com: Is there a way to show notification from bash script in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/31917/is-there-a-way-to-show-notification-from-bash-script-in-ubuntu/1310142#1310142)

Answer (score 3):

**ffmpeg sine wave**

For the minimalists out there, you can play a 1000 Hz sine for 5 seconds:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffplay -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000:duration=5" -autoexit -nodisp
```

or forever until you do Ctrl-C:

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=1000" -nodisp
```

More information at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109038/linux-sine-wave-audio-generator/57610684#57610684

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04, ffmpeg 3.4.6.

Comment: This sometimes makes a sound, sometimes not. Do you know why?

Comment: @BetoAveiga I haven't observed that, let me know if you figure out.

Answer (score 3):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> on your keyboard while on the terminal window that is running the command and when the command finishes it'll beep. If you press it multiple times it will beep many times as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
command && (say done ; echo done) || (echo error ; say error)
```

Example 1: `echo alik && (say done ; echo done) || (echo error ; say error)` will result in a done word.

Example 2: `non_existing_command_error && (say done ; echo done) || (echo error ; say error)` will result in an error word.

* Needs `gnustep-gui-runtime` -

```
sudo apt-get install gnustep-gui-runtime
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple and almost-native script that plays Sound and displays a Notification with a Given Message and Time for Ubuntu ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/John-Almardeny/04fb95eeb969aa46f031457c7815b07d)):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# https://gist.github.com/John-Almardeny/04fb95eeb969aa46f031457c7815b07d
# Create a Notification With Sound with a Given Message and Time
# The Downloaded Sound is from Notification Sounds https://notificationsounds.com/

MSSG="$1"
TIME="$2"

# install wget if not found
if ! [ -x "$(command -v wget)" ]; then 
    echo -e "INSTALLING WGET...\n\n"
    sudo apt-get install wget
    echo -e "\n\n"
fi

# install at package if not found
if ! [ -x "$(command -v at)" ]; then
    echo -e "INSTALLING AT...\n\n"
    sudo apt-get install at
    echo -e "\n\n"
fi

# install sox if not found
if ! [ -x "$(command -v sox)" ]; then
    echo -e "INSTALLING SOX...\n\n"
    sudo apt-get install sox
    sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all
    echo -e "\n\n"
fi

# download the noti sound if this is first time
# add alias to the bashrc file
if ! [ -f ~/noti/sound.mp3 ]; then
    echo -e "DOWNLOADING SOUND...\n\n"
    touch ~/noti/sound.mp3 | wget -O ~/noti/sound.mp3 "https://notificationsounds.com/wake-up-tones/rise-and-shine-342/download/mp3"
    sudo echo "alias noti=\"sh ~/noti/noti.sh\"" >> ~/.bashrc
    source ~/.bashrc        
    echo -e "\n\n"
fi

# notify with the sound playing and particular given message and time
echo "notify-send \""$MSSG\"" && play ~/noti/sound.mp3" | at $TIME
```

#### How To Use?

#### First Run - Setting Up:

1. Create a new Directory at your home and call it `noti`

   ```
   mkdir ~/noti
   ```
2. Download [noti.sh](https://gist.github.com/John-Almardeny/04fb95eeb969aa46f031457c7815b07d/archive/5502b0060e2a88f3a843b1c5d92c60ad229d7d64.zip)  and extract it to the above `noti` dir.
3. Open Terminal and Change Directory to `noti`

   ```
   cd ~/noti
   ```
4. Make noti.sh executable by issuing:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x noti.sh
   ```
5. Run a Test like this:

   ```
   sh ~/noti/noti.sh "Test" "now"
   ```

#### Examples

```
noti "Hello From Noti" "now +1 minute"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now +5 minutes"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now + 1 hour"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now + 2 days"
noti "Hello From Noti" "4 PM + 2 days"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now + 3 weeks"
noti "Hello From Noti" "now + 4 months"
noti "Hello From Noti" "4:00 PM"
noti "Hello From Noti" "2:30 AM tomorrow"
noti "Hello From Noti" "2:30 PM Fri"
noti "Hello From Noti" "2:30 PM 25.07.18"
```

#### For Notifying The Finish of Process (example)

```
sudo apt-get update; noti "Done" "now"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding an interesting idea i've seen implemented in some scripts, using the system bell:

```
tput bel
```

it will ring the system bell, which (at least in konsole) shows a notification if you're not watching the terminal and does nothing if you are watching it (in old termnals it might ring an actual bell).
according to [this quesiton](https://superuser.com/questions/969080/how-to-ring-the-system-bell-from-command-line) it is very portable, it even works in macOS and doesn't need anything to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

either `aplay` or `spd-say` is enough if you want to play a sound. but if you want some nice bell ding as default then [ding](https://github.com/coolcorexix/ding) can be a suitable choice, just

```
ding npm install
```

or

```
docker build && docker tag && docker push && ding
```

to set a reminder when the command is done

Answer (score 0):

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/purple/alert.wav
```

and for ease of remembering make it an alias in .bashrc

```
alias beep="aplay /usr/share/sounds/purple/alert.wav 2>/dev/null"
```

you can then type beep and it will beep (oh my)