# `terminator` terminal won't play bell sound

Tags: command-line, sound, gnome-terminal, terminator

On my PC, inside `gnome-terminal` in Ubuntu 18.04, the bell sound plays just fine when I run this:

```
echo -e "\a"
```

However, in the `terminator` terminal (`sudo apt install terminator`), which I now use as default because it has beautiful [screen windowing abilities](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/issues/280), it won't play the sound! Why not?

---

*NOT A DUPLICATE: This is not a duplicate of other Questions, such as this one ([Beep in shell script not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working)), because I am asking specifically about the `terminator` terminal. My bell sound works fine in other terminals, for instance, but not in `terminator`. This is a new, unique question.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out you just have to enable the setting! (It comes *disabled* by default).

**Right-click on the `terminator` screen --> Preferences --> click the "Profiles" tab at the top --> ensure the "General" sub-tab is chosen --> check the box for "Audible beep" under the "Terminal bell" section in the bottom-right:**

[image]

That's it! Works perfectly now--same as in `gnome-terminal`, even over ssh:

```
echo -e "\a"
```

## Related:

1. [Beep in shell script not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working/1253794#1253794)

Comment: In addition to enabling the "Audible beep", I also had to load the `module-x11-bell` module in pulseaudio (see https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=736811#p736811)