# Programmable periodic alarm with start and end time

Tags: software-recommendation, clock

I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284264/alarm-clock-for-ubuntu) question and I've a similar request but not identical.
I need a programmable alarm clock with the following features:

- set the interval in minutes
- set the begin and end time

For example I want to setup an alarm that fires from 10:00 to 18:00 every 90 minutes.
Nice to have (even not mandatory) to set on which days should run.

I tried the Gnome Clock Applet and Teatime but they do not fit my requirements.

Comment: Have you tried the calendar? I think the Gnome Shell calendar integrates with Evolution.

Comment: @mchid it allows me to set a repetition among weekdays, not during the day

Comment: Have you considered cron/systemd.timer launching a video player?

Comment: @DanielT of course I can even write an application by myself. I just wonder if there is something ready to use, without having to reinvent the wheel :)