# Make a sound if the command lasted more than X minutes

Tags: command-line, bash, sound

I'm aware it's already been asked how to [make a sound after a command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/make-a-sound-once-process-is-complete#).

Despite people seem to intend to use it after long-running commands, there is initially **no connexion between the actual trick and the duration of the command**.

My question here is, can I (using bash or zsh) make my terminal execute a script that would wrap every command looking at `start time` and comparing when it finishes to `end time` and **if and only if the command lasted more than X minutes**, the sound is played?

Because in practice, those long running commands are often new and there is no chance I anticipate this every time!

*Bonus*: the sound should not be played for interactive commands (eg. `ssh xxx`), if it is too hard, the criteria could be whether the focus is given to the window or not.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Short answer : no , what you ask about  doesn't exist.

Comment: You can , however, make a wrapper function and append append it to each command in a script. See this answer : http://askubuntu.com/a/409766/295286

Comment: @Serg what you reported is exactly what I was looking for! A sound or a desktop notification will definitely be interchangeable.

Comment: Glad my commend was useful. Just FYI: you can use `aplay` command instead of `notify-send` that is used in the other answer to play some sort of mp3 file with notification sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea, might be useful for me too in the future and was a nice excuse to learn bash, sorry for any common mistakes, just slapped this script into existence from a bunch of Google searches in less than 15 min.

Usage: `script.sh "command" 29` (29 is the time in seconds) and I didn't implement the actual command to make the sound. You have to google the best option for your needs and replace it

```
#!/bin/bash
eval $1 &
PID=$!
let "timer=0"
let "increase=1"
let "mtime=$2"
while true; do
    if [ "$(ps -p $PID -o pid=)" = "" ]; then exit; fi
    let "timer=timer+increase"
    if [[ timer -gt mtime ]]; then
        let "timer=0"
        let "increase=0"
        replaceme-with-sound-command
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

And no, I do not know any method to warp every command into some other, best-case-scenario you can remove the extension and put the above script somewhere in your $PATH with a short name like 'tm' to ease of access

Comment: Thanks for the try. Look at @Serg link, it seems really helpful. If you are on a learning dynamic, I'd encourage you to have a look at zsh callbacks just like this question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169090/zsh-behavior-on-enter