# Elementary OS terminal bell in UBUNTU

Tags: command-line, notification, terminal-bell

I recently shifted from Elementary OS to UBUNTU 20.04 LTS. One very useful feature on Elementary OS was the terminal bell. When a command in terminal is done executing, there is a bell ring sound and a notification in the notification area.

This can be achieved by using `notify-send "Task Complete" && printf '\a'` along with the original command by using `&&`.

But here is the catch:
1. This command is very long and needs to be typed every time. `alias` can be used but still you have to type it every time.
2. It rings this even when the terminal is in focus.

So my question is, I want a specific command to execute every time which is `notify-send "Task Complete" && printf '\a'` only when terminal is out of focus. And that too without typing this every time.

**EDIT 1**
Some people suggested [How to make a sound once a process is complete?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/how-to-make-a-sound-once-a-process-is-complete)
But my question was to ring the bell without typing any extra command. Is there a way I could integrate some script or something in the terminal itself, so that it calls the beep sound on its own without any extra commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a sound once a process is complete?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/how-to-make-a-sound-once-a-process-is-complete)

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/742826/250300)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a satisfactory solution. It uses `oh-my-zsh`. There is a plugin called `bg-notify` which does exactly what the question asked for. It even sends a notification in the notification bar, along with an audio cue.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

I've come up with my own concoction using `xdotool` (`sudo apt-get install xdotool`) and `pstree` (`sudo apt-get install psmisc`).

```
#! /bin/bash
ACTIVE_WINDOW_PID=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid)
if [ ! $(pstree -spA $PPID | grep "(${ACTIVE_WINDOW_PID})") ]; then
  notify-send "Task Complete" && printf '\a'
fi
```

I have this in `~/bin/ring` and I used the following command to verify if it works: `sleep 3 ; ~/bin/ring`.

Using `xdotool` you could even get the window title and report it using `notify-send`, or focus the terminal window when the command exists.